# Looking for an "SMA signal polarity inverter"

Tags: cables, adapter

I found one of these lying around in my microwave/RF lab and I was wondering if it has a technical name and if I can build one myself:
[image]

It has SMA connectors at the two ends. It flips the polarity of the input signal and also attenuates it a bit (~10dB).

It's currently hooked up in a signal pathway which carries a "sync signal" spike train at 10MHz and 0-2V DC. We are using one of these guys to flip it into an NIM (nuclear instrumentation) compatible spike train of that goes 0 to -1VDC.

Searching online for "SMA signal inverter" or " SMA polarity inverter" doesn't give any useful results. I see many search results on reverse-polarity SMA adapters but that's something completely different.

It turns out this thing has two pieces - an "inverter" (the shrink wrapped piece on the left) and a standard 10dB attenuator which is easily available off the shelf.

I don't understand how the inverter works. After unwrapping the shrink wrap on one of them I see something that looks like this:

[image]

The resistance for the 4 terminal combinations are all close to ~2 ohms on a multimeter i.e. basically short circuit at DC.

Comment: Yeah, but why would you want to? Then the shield is on the inside and the signal on the outside. You'll also want to edit your question, product recommendations questions are off topic

Comment: Thanks @laptop2d. I edited my question - hopefully it sounds less like a product recommendation. Also added a quick summary of why I need it.

Comment: Can you add a diagram of how the two pins from each connector are attached to each other?  Use a multimeter and also include the resistance measurements from each of the 4 possible ways to connect the meter probes to the connectors.

Comment: How it works: the black component in the middle is a balun (a type of RF transformer). The input goes to ground trough the primary, inducing a voltage into the secondary. By connecting the right end of the secondary to the output and the other to ground, the signal gets inverted.

Comment: @jms: Answers should go into the"Your Answer" section below, not in the comments.

Comment: @DaveTweed Sure, I just thought that it's a bit too low effort for posting as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How it works: the black component in the middle is a balun (a type of transformer for RF applications). The input goes to ground trough the primary, inducing a voltage into the secondary. By connecting the right end of the secondary to the output and the other to ground, the signal gets inverted. Reflections, distortion and attention are minimized by selecting a balun that presents an impedance at the signal frequency which matches that of the transmission line (50 ohms).

The attenuator is responsible for the 10 db attenuation you see.

Comment: Thanks! So, if my cables and terminations are all 50ohms, can I use a 50ohm 1:1 ratio 3GHz balun? Also, can I use a balun without the center tap (the extra third unused terminal)?

Comment: Technically this is not a balun.  A balun is a transformer specifically for converting between balanced and unbalanced lines, but this has connectors for unbalanced signals on both ends.  It might or might not be made from a transformer that could be used as a balun in a different application.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The component is a off-the-shelf balun, as jms said. It is not being used as a balun. That is why it has an extra unused leg (the center tap for the balanced side)